# Why does the jumpingfunction not work? What am i missing? unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As said in the title, the jumpfunction doesn't work (the character simply doesn't jumps), but the rest works perfectly fine. What's wrong/ what am i missing?

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    Vector2 jump;
    void Start () {
        rb = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        jump  = new Vector2 (9f, 20f);
        Debug.Log (jump.ToString());  //works, outputs 9,20
    }

    void Update () {
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2 ((Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")* speed), 0);
        rb.AddForce(movement);  //works fine...
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) {
            Debug.Log ("Gets called1"); //works
            Jump ();
        }
    }
    void Jump (){
        rb.AddForce (jump);
        Debug.Log("Gets called2"); //works

    }

}
```

Can you help me?  [Rigidbody settings picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKYMB.png)

Comment: Increase `speed ` to something bigger such as 100, 200... Also post screenshot of your rigidbody settings

Comment: rigidbody is on the default settings (didn't changed anything)

Comment: What happens if you put `rb.AddForce (jump);` in the Update function?

Comment: @Programmer thx, increasing speed did the Job xD.

Comment: Anytime. Happy coding!